# Why are ArcGIS Server SOC machines removed from host after Windows Update?

Tags: arcgis-server

Whenever Windows service pack updated on our servers, SOC machines were automatically removed from HOSTS. Is this a known behaviour? Are there any ESRI tech support articles on this? Machines are Win2008 R2 with ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Hi Please explain your question in detail with the software specification..Did you get any error message after update? Do you have admin rights?Is it single box installation or distributed installation ?

Comment: Did you apply SP4 for ArcGIS Server 10.0 ?

Comment: This is not SP update, routine MS security patche updates. This will be done by IT team. No specific error messages, but SOC has been removed from the hosts automatically.